# Clock update on every boot

Tags: boot, updates

My laptop computer cmos battery isn't working. i want replace but i need to make drawings on autocad for this reason i cant send my laptop to service.
in windows 8 there wasnt any problem but i have installed win 7 and every internet sites gives sertificate errors caused by clock and date.
how i can update windows clock on every boot ?
i tried atomic clock program but it doesnt update. only i can update clock manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my PC, I solved it using [SmallSNTPAgent](http://alsedi.com/small_sntp_agent.php), a small free software that updates system datetime.

You can execute it at Windows startup and you can also define the time server to be used for time sync.

It has a small GUI, but it can also run in silent mode

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried w32tm service?

This site has a nice little page on it, unless you are on a domain in which case you should sync from an AD server.

https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/info/ntp-w32time.htm

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.